# writing a recursive function using foldr

Tags: haskell, lambda, fold

I am new in Haskell programming.
While practicing I was asked to make a recursive function that looks like this:

```
repeat1 5 [1,2,3] = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

which is

```
repeat1 :: Int -> a -> [a]
repeat1 0 x = []
repeat1 num x = x : repeat1 (num-1) x
```

I want to convert it into a `foldr` function but I can't :(
I have read about the lambda functions and the folding(`foldr` and `foldl`) functions from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/List_processing

Can anybody help please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can of course write `repeat1 num x = foldr (\_ xs -> x : xs) [] [1 .. num]`, but that's not really a good way to write it. The explicit recursion is the best way.

Comment: @hammar, you might expand your `unfoldr` comment into a full answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foldr` is for functions that consume lists. For producing lists, `unfoldr` is a more natural choice:

```
repeat1 :: Int -> a -> [a]
repeat1 n x = unfoldr f n
  where f 0 = Nothing
        f n = Just (x, n-1)
```

That said, I think writing it as a plain recursion is more clear in this case.

Answer (score 2):

As hammar pointed out, `foldr` isn't the right tool here, as you first need a list to work on. Why not simply...

```
repeat1 n = take n . repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `foldr`, you could do something like that:

```
repeat' n x = foldr (\_ acc -> x:acc) [] [1..n]
```

You basically create a list of size `n` with `[1..n]` and for each element of that list, you append `x` to your accumulator (base value `[]`). In the end you have a n-elements list of `x`.